# glDrawElements extremally slow on Android ( HTC Wildfire )

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm testing OpenGL performance on an Android phone ( HTC Wildfire to be exact ), and I came across a strange thing - when I try to draw a textured indexed rectangle the size of the screen ( 320 x 480 ), I can get a framerate up to 40 fps!!! - and that's only when I use a 32x32 texture.

If I increase the texture size to 256x256, the performance drops down to 35 frames.

My question is - how is it possible for all those Android games to run smoothly and still be so full of cool graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of different ways to eek performance out of your device.

1. Make sure you aren't doing blending, or drawing that you don't need and from experience a lot of the lower end HTC devices (eg the desire) are fill rate limited.
2. Use triangle strips instead of triangles.
3. Use draw elements and cache your calls eg load your vertex buffer and call draw multiple times for a frame.

**But most importantly use the DDMS** with method profiling to determine where your bottle necks actually are they may be places you don't expect them eg logging, gc, slow operation in a loop. You will be able to see how much of the time is due to rendering and how much for other operations. (look for GLImpl.glDrawElements)

My biggest ones were with GC kicking in too often (5 times per second and causing my fps to be very sluggish), something you will see with mem allocations often in places you won't even think of. Eg if you are concatenating a string to a float with the + operator or using traditional java get() functions everywhere or (worst) collections, these create a large number of objects that can trigger GC.

Also if you have expensive operations separate them out into a separate thread.

Also I am assuming you are creating your texture once and using the same index each time. I have seen some tutorials which create the texture every time a frame is rendered.

With extensive use of the DDMS I was able to take fps from 12 to 50 on the HTC Desire for a busy scene.

Hope that gets you going in the right direction :)

Comment: Like I mentioned, I'm testing the performance - so I'm using just one texture thats loaded and bound to the device only once, and then I'm just drawing two indexed triangles using GL10.GL_TRIANGLES call - nothing more. The thing is that those two triangles cover up the whole screen. So what worries me is that simply bit belting a texture the size of a screen to the back buffer COSTS THAT MUCH

Comment: Hi Paksas I'm currently using several dozen 128x128 textures with AI, collision detection and a bunch of other things going on and I'm able to achieve 40 - 50 fps on the HTC desire. 80% of my rendering time is currently spent drawing the menu and debug information and that is after heavily optimizing out all GC operations out with custom string handlers (My DrawNumber function takes 31% alone). If you post your code we can take a look at it but I would still highly recommend using the Method profiler and allocation tracker to see if your application is waiting anywhere before rendering.

Comment: Actually to compare the devices directly, run Smartbench 2011 free from the android store, and compare values. The desire gets 1134 for cpu and 546 for graphics. Thats should give us a relative scale between the devices.

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience, they don't on devices like the wildfire.